Migrating from Spring cloud oauth2 to spring security after Springboot 3.0.0 upgrade
After migrating my project from Springboot security 2.7 to 3.0, i find myself in a bit of a migration trouble.
I have correctly migrated whole project ot use jakarta dependencies instead of javax, but the only thing that remains is to migrate the deprecated Spring cloud oauth2 configuration.
I am using org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.2.5.RELEASE in my project that is a basically a access token resourceserver. After update to 3.0 which now prefers Spring security instead of Spring cloud oath2 i cannot for the life of me, migrate my custom classes and methods.
I was hoping for some tips and guidance which would help me migrate my codebase:
Replaced ResourceSeverConfiguration with SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")
    private String jwkSetUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.token-info-trust:}")
    private String API_TRUST_PATH;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.token-info-trust-key:}")
    private String API_TRUST_KEY;

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    private final MySecurityResourceProperties properties;

    public SecurityConfig(CacheManager cacheManager, @Qualifier("mySecurityResourceProperties") MySecurityResourceProperties properties) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("some_endpoint").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("some_endpoint").authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                        )
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setAccessTokenConverter(new JwtConverter());
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenServices() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new MyRemoteTokenServices(
                cacheManager, this.API_TRUST_PATH, this.API_TRUST_KEY);
        tokenServices.setClientId(properties.getClientId());
        tokenServices.setClientSecret(properties.getClientSecret());
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(properties.getTokenInfoUri());
        tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        return tokenServices;
    }

    public static class JwtConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter implements JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configure(JwtAccessTokenConverter converter) {
            converter.setAccessTokenConverter(this);
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
            OAuth2Authentication auth = super.extractAuthentication(map);
            auth.setDetails(map);
            return auth;
        }
    }



Deprecated DefaultAccessTokenConverter, OAuth2Authentication, JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer, RemoteTokenServices, AccessTokenConverter

Deprecated RemoteTokenServices which is implemented in MyRemoteTokenServices class

package si.osi.rekonoapi.server.services;

import java.io.IOException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import lombok.NonNull;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices;
import org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import si.osi.rekonoapi.server.utils.Utils;

/**
 * Custom token services calls.
 * Allows us to add our own trust and parse the token on our own.
 */
public class MyRemoteTokenServices extends RemoteTokenServices {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRemoteTokenServices.class);

    private Cache cache;

    public MyRemoteTokenServices(CacheManager cacheManager, String trustPath, String trustKey) {
        super();

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = Utils.prepareRestClient(
                    "RemoteTokenServices",
                    null,  null,
                    trustPath, trustKey);

            restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                // Ignore 400
                public void handleError(@NonNull ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.getStatusCode().value() != 400) {
                        super.handleError(response);
                    }
                }
            });

            super.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
            this.cache = cacheManager.getCache("accessTokens");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Cannot init service {}, message: {}", "RemoteTokenServices", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken) throws AuthenticationException,
            InvalidTokenException {
        if (this.isExpired(accessToken)) {
            cache.evictIfPresent(accessToken);
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Token is expired.");
        }

        OAuth2Authentication result = cache.get(accessToken, OAuth2Authentication.class);
        if (result == null) {
            LOG.trace("Authentication info present in cache. Calling openid...");
            result = super.loadAuthentication(accessToken);
            cache.put(accessToken, result);
        } else {
            LOG.trace("Authentication info present in cache. Token not expired, reusing...");
        }
        return SerializationUtils.clone(result);
    }

    private boolean isExpired(String accessToken) {
        try {
            String withoutSignature = accessToken.substring(0, accessToken.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            Jwts.parserBuilder().build().parseClaimsJwt(withoutSignature);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException exc) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}



I was trying to migrate to different approach to remove deprecated RemoteTokenService, but i cannot find any replacements or methods to use from Spring security.

I would like to preserve all custom handling logic but it seems that none of the help of migration tutorials did the job.
Due to mismatch of underlying dependencies with this deprecated Spring cloud oath2 i cannot continue to fix the problem of casting the OAuth2authentication token, because its not compatible in the new spring security oauth2.
My dependencies
    // spring-boot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.2.5.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:6.3.0'


Couldn't decode token... Error: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication (org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken and org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @5c29bfd) []


Any sort of help or pointers would be much appreciated.
